# php code for find largest and second largest number without using array

Tags: php, html

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
   <input name="txt1" type="text" /><br />
   <input name="txt2" type="text" /><br />
   <input name="txt3" type="text" /><br />
   <input name="s" type="submit" value="Find No"/>
   </form>
```

Here is my html code.

```
    <?php

    $a = 10;
    $b = 25;
    $c = 20;

    if($a > $b)
    {
  if($a > $c)
 {
 echo "a is biggest number";
 }
else
 {
 echo "c is biggest number";
 }
}
if($b > $c)
{
echo "b is biggest number";
}

?>
```

`    Here is the code for finding

largest among three no.s . I wish to get largest and second largest no

Comment: I dont understand your question. What do you mean by "using inputs given through text fields" ? are all the text fields named the same? Please give an example :)

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of numerical strings obtained from the input fields, for example one that mirrors your original values:

```
$a = array('1', '5', '19', '200', '999');
```

you can convert it into a true numerical array using the following approach:

```
$a = array_map('intval', $a);
```

and then proceed exactly as you did before:

```
$last = max($a);
$second = max(array_diff($a,[$last]));
```

Fiddle [here](https://eval.in/929838).

Answer (score 1):

you have to use input box for this and a submit button for very simple basic working model.

HTML:

```
<form action="/path to your php file or leave blank if both html and php are in same file">
<input type="text" name="arr" value=''>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

// now user can provide input with space in input box such as 9 11 13 15 16 29 etc.

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['arr']) && !empty($_REQUEST['arr'])){
        $a = explode(' ', $_REQUEST['arr']);
        $last = max($a);
        $second = max(array_diff($a,[$last]));
        echo $second;
        echo $last;
?>
```

I think this will resolve your query.

Comment: My bad. I just copied code from question only to explain only.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Here we use reverse array sort  with largest and second largest number**

```
$result = array(1,5,19,200,999);
$count = count($result);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){   
   for($j=$i+1;$j<$count;$j++){   
      if($result[$i]<$result[$j]){
        $m = $result[$i];
        $result[$i] = $result[$j];
        $result[$j] = $m;
      }
   }
 }
echo "Largest Number : ".(!empty($result[0])?$result[0]:FALSE)." Largest Second Number : ".(!empty($result[1])?$result[1]:FALSE);
```